# Manipulate image without using flash

Tags: image, client-side, server-side

I want user to dynamically change an image as per user needs -- like Add or delete any component of the image when user opts for that and also change color of any component when needed like in case of laptop color.
How can i achieve that without using flash -- can be server side or client side.

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate images very well using HTML5 canvas but what you're looking for is more like a *CRUD* image manipulation example. For that check out this one:

[www.grocerycrud.com/image-crud/](http://www.grocerycrud.com/image-crud/)